# how to assume roles twice (or multiple times) in the script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, assume-role

I am trying to assume a role twice in the script, I assume the role first like this

```
import boto3 session = boto3.Session(profile_name="learnaws-test")
sts = session.client("sts")
response = sts.assume_role(
RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/s3-readonly-access",
RoleSessionName="learnaws-test-session"
)
new_session = Session(aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'], aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'], aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken'])
```

but after I have done this, I understand I can use this new_session to access s3 buckets or whatever resourse and stuff but I need to assume another role from this role, how do I assume another role?

logically, I think from this "new_session" we have to do something to assume another role, but what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Call AssumeRole

When calling `AssumeRole()`, a new set of credentials is returned. You can then use these credentials to create new clients, including another Security Token Service (STS) client that can be used to call `AssumeRole()` again.

Here is an example:

```py
import boto3

# Create STS client using default credentials

sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

# Assume Role 1

response1 = sts_client.assume_role(RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/assume1', RoleSessionName='One')

credentials1 = response1['Credentials']

role1_session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=credentials1['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials1['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials1['SessionToken'])

sts_client1 = role1_session.client('sts')

# Assume Role 2

response2 = sts_client1.assume_role(RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/assume2', RoleSessionName='Two')

credentials2 = response2['Credentials']

role2_session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=credentials2['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials2['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials2['SessionToken'])

# Use Role 2

s3_client2 = role2_session.client('s3')

response = s3_client2.list_buckets()

print(response)
```

#### Use profiles

However, **there is an easier way to do this using profiles**. You can configure the `~/.aws/config` file to assume roles automatically:

```
[default]
region = ap-southeast-2

[profile role1]
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/assume1
source_profile=default

[profile role2]
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/assume2
source_profile=role1
```

This is telling boto3:

- When assuming `role1`, use the `default` credentials
- When assuming `role2`, use credentials from `role1`

Assuming both roles is then as simple as:

```py
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='role2')
s3_client = session.client('s3')

response = s3_client.list_buckets()

print(response)
```

This also works with the AWS CLI:

```
aws s3 ls --profile role2
```

For more information, see: [Credentials — Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html)

Comment: thank you so much for this detailed answer, really helped me a lot. I am basically following the first method you displayed but I am passing a sso profile (credentials stored in the .aws/config file) when assuming the first role. Just wanted to ask you, that's not a problem, right? 
because the only reason I am passing a profile is that I don't what boto3 to use the default profile from the config folder.

Comment: It should work fine. Just point the `source_profile` to the profile that contains the 'base' authentication (eg your SSO).